# gams syntax issue - "set identifier or quoted element expected"

Tags: cplex, gams

Writing some GAMS code, getting some syntax errors:

[image]

Anyone recognize the problem?

Comment: Indexing by a set is `x(j)` and by a set element: `x('jan')`. Indexing by a variable is not allowed. You don't need to capitalize everything.

Comment: Code (text) should be quoted as text and not uploaded as images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On line 134, I suspect you meant X(J) instead of X(Y) and XX(J) instead of XX(Y).  Also, it looks you have an inconsistency with months as strings JAN, ..., DEC versus integers $1, \dots, 12$.